# Error in applying apply function for removing outliers in mulitple columns of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: A sample dataframe with 8 columns]

The actual dataframe is huge, so I am showing a small dataframe so that you can reproduce with your outputs.

```
data = {'X1': [3,5,8,3,5,19,5],
        'X2': [2,7,9,1,14,2,10],
        'X3': [1,8,23,14,4,9,5],
        'X4': [5,3,1,6,9,23,12]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I am trying to remove the outliers for all features. Thus, I applied the apply function, but it gave me an error. So kindly help. Secondly, I also want to know if I could just use FOR loops to execute it.

```
def remove(df):
    for i in df:
        Q1 = df[i].quantile(0.25)
        Q3 = df[i].quantile(0.75)
        IQR = Q3 - Q1
        lower = (Q1 - 1.5*IQR)
        upper = (Q3 + 1.5*IQR)
         
        upper_array = np.where(df[i] >= upper)[0]
        lower_array = np.where(df[i] <= lower)[0]
    
   df.drop(index=upper_array, inplace=True)
   df.drop(index=lower_array, inplace=True)

   return df



df = df.apply(remove,axis=1)
df.head()
```

Secondly,

How can I do this with simple for loops? I tried some code, but I am not able to get through.

```
lower = []
upper = []
for i in df:
    Q1 = df[i].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df[i].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    lower.append(Q1 - 1.5*IQR)
    upper.append(Q3 + 1.5*IQR)
    
for i in df:
        upper_array = np.where(df[i] >= upper)[0]
        lower_array = np.where(df[i] <= lower)[0]

df.drop(index=upper_array, inplace=True)
df.drop(index=lower_array, inplace=True)
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible input, not an image, and explain what you're trying to do: removing all rows that have an outlier in any of the column?

Comment: What happens if outliers for the different columns lie on different rows? Do you really want to drop every row with an outlier? How is IQR defined?

Comment: @mozway I have provided the sample dataframe, kindly provide me the solution.

Comment: @Raagibkhan I already provided an answer below (assuming you want to remove the full row if any feature has an outlier)

Comment: @mozway thankyou for your resolution, however I just want to remove that particular value which is an outlier for each and every feature variable. If it's assigned nan or zero that can later me imputed with any imputation techniques.

Comment: @Raagibkhan ok, then use `out = df.mask(outlier)` or `out = df.mask(outlier, value_of_interest)` with `outlier` the mask from my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use for loops to remove outliers, you can vectorize the method.

Assuming this example input:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(100, 8)))
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'X{x+1}')
      )
```

Compute the [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), then the IQR, and identify the outliers with [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html)/[`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html). Then use [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to flag the rows with at least one outlier to filter them with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

outlier = df.lt(Q1 - 1.5*IQR) | df.gt(Q3 + 1.5*IQR)

out = df[~outlier.any(axis=1)]
```

Graph of the input dataset:

[image]

Dataset after filtering the outliers (shown as grey dots):

[image]